# Cannot bind JSON in Golang Gin to struct with ManyToMany field

Tags: algorithm, go, backend, go-gorm, go-gin

I have the following structs as relational models:

```golang
type Product struct {
    ID          uint32     `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment" json:"id"`
    Name        string     `gorm:"size:100;not null" json:"name"`
    Description string     `gorm:"size:512" json:"description"`
    Price       float64    `gorm:"default:0" json:"price"`
    Shop        Shop       `json:"shop"`
    ShopID      uint32     `gorm:"not null" json:"shop_id"`
    Categories  []Category `gorm:"many2many:product_categories;" json:"categories"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time  `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time  `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
}

type Category struct {
    ID        uint32    `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment" json:"id"`
    Name      string    `gorm:"size:100;not null" json:"name"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
}
```

Now, on my controller I want to create a Product with multiple categories from a JSON object but I can't find a way on how to do it; thus, it returns the message *Unable to bind data to product*. Here is the code:

```golang
func (s *Server) createProduct(c *gin.Context) {
    uid, err := auth.ExtractTokenID(c.Request)
    if err != nil {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"message": "Unauthorized"})
        return
    }
    var product = models.Product{}
    var shop = models.Shop{}

    if err := c.BindJSON(&product); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"message": "Unable to bind data to product"})
        return
    }
```

Is there a solution or a simple way on how to achieve this? As I haven't been able to find anything on `gorm` documentation.

Edit; Here is the JSON object I'm sending:

```json
{
    "name": "Soap",
    "description": "Smelly Soap",
    "Price": 12.99,
    "categories": [1]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the request body too?

Comment: @Mihai It's up, I edited the post

Comment: Thank you, I think the issue is with your json indeed. You pass the categories in the request under `product_categories` but the json tag on your struct is `categories`. Also, to correctly unmarshal you will need to provide the full Category structure in the array not only the id.

Comment: Thank you @Mihai I've solved it by creater an interface on which to bind the request body, take an array containing ManyToMany IDs, retrieve categories from that array and into the product a set of Category structs. Not the cleanest way to do it; but it works, maybe it just needs some refactoring